# AWS Auto-Scaling Testing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, aws-auto-scaling

How do I test if my AWS auto scaling is working fine? Any lead to find a way to test this feature through Automation ? My aim is to make load on the servers and check if new AWS instances are spinning up and down as per requirement (through automation). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I presume you are referring to Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling? What are the settings of your scaling alarms? To test that they are working, you would need to simulate load that triggers those alarms.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache Bench or Apache JMeter to generate load on your website to test scaling.

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html and http://jmeter.apache.org/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion